# ADB does not stop restarting spontaneously in a random way

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

ADB does not stop restarting spontaneously in a random way which causes it to lose the connected devices either real device (by wifi or usb) or the emulator.

[image]

Difficult to work in these conditions.

I did a new installation of android studio but without success...

Any ideas ?

How do I know it’s ADB rebooting? When I work (with a WiFi device) and I see that my console loses the phone, I go to the console right away and reinsert the command `adb connect my-device-ip`. I can see the terminal display:

```
* daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
* daemon started successfully
```

As if I had made the command `adb start-server`.

- Android Studio Chipmunk : 2021.2.1 Patch 1
- Android Emulator : 31.2.10
- Android SDK Platform Tools : 33.0.2
- Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HXM installer) : 7.6.5
- Windows 10 Professional

So everything seems up-to-date.

Thank's for your help.

Comment: adb is a program and so like any other program it can crash. Based on your description I would assume that adb is crashing. Try a different adb version, may be it is more stable.